# Multiple Django applications using virtualenv on Apache 2 on Ubuntu 11

Tags: django, apache, virtualenv, mod-wsgi

I've successfully setup one Django application using `virtualenv` on Ubuntu and Apache 2, using the `WSGIPythonHome` directive pointing to my `virtualenv` location.  Now I am in need to create a separate Django application, that is going to run on Apache on a different port on the same Ubuntu server.  I am wondering if there's a way to have Apache run multiple `WSGIPythonHome` instances?  Currently with `WSGIPythonHome` being set to one `virtualenv` root, there's a problem with imports on the second Django app…

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this, I've discovered about a year ago, is to use WSGI as a daemon and set the python path in the daemon directive.  Example is below

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName yourhost.com

    <Directory />
      Order deny,allow
      #Require all granted
    </Directory>

    #Alias /static /opt/yourhost/static
    WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/yourhost/wsgi.py

    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

    WSGIDaemonProcess yourhost.com python-path=/opt/yourhost:/opt/yourhost/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages processes=2 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP}
    WSGIProcessGroup  yourhost.com
</VirtualHost>
WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/wsgi
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do this with separate [virtual hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/) in Apache. Each one can listen to a particular port, and can have its own separate WSGI directives.

Comment: I do have virtual hosts setup for each of the apps.  Where in the virtual host config do I add a WSGI.  What's the syntax.  I tried a quick google search about virtual hosts and WSGI before posting the question but found nothing helpful

Comment: import os, sys
import site
site.addsitedir('/home/deploy/virtualenv/expenses/lib/python2.6/site-packages')
sys.path.append('/opt/expenses/current/src')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'expenses.settings'
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()

Comment: above is my wsgi directive, i have two, one for each app...but i see no where, where i can add a WSGIPythonHome directive

Comment: Why are you posting your wsgi file? That has nothing to do with it. You do it in the Apache configuration for each virtual host.

Comment: <VirtualHost *:9090>
ServerName www.webikentrading.net
WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/expenses/current/src/expenses/django.wsgi
Alias /static /opt/expenses/current/src/expenses/common/static
<Directory /opt/expenses/current/src/expenses/common/static >
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
<Directory /opt/expenses/current/src >
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>