# upgrading python for django site running on Apache & wsgi

Tags: django, python-3.x, apache, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I'm trying to switch a django site from running in python 3.6 to python 3.7 on Ubuntu 16.04. To do so I created a new environment in the same path as the old and have re-installed all of the dependencies.

The Apache server, however, fails with the following error:

```
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'
```

Which error, after a bit of research, seems to be due to the WSGI configuration, as per:

> You cannot for example force mod_wsgi to use a Python virtual
>   environment created using Python 3.5 when mod_wsgi was originally
>   compiled for Python 2.7. This is because the Python library for the
>   Python installation it was originally compiled against is linked
>   directly into the mod_wsgi module. In other words, Python is embedded
>   within mod_wsgi. When mod_wsgi is used it does not run the command
>   line python program to run the interpreter and thus why you can’t
>   force it to use a different Python installation.

from: https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html

thanks to: [Django Apache wsgi changes python version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40946211/django-apache-wsgi-changes-python-version/40982597#40982597)

The OP in the above ended up just wiping the setup clean and starting from scratch. This seems a bit extreme to me, as it seems like I should just be able to re-install/re-configure mod-wsgi to run with python3.7

In this line of thinking, I uninstalled and reinstalled both, libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 and mod_wsgi. The former, however, just reconfigures to 3.6 automatically, as seen below:

```
root@server1:~# dpkg -S mod_wsgi
libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so
libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so-3.6
```

and the mod_wsgi installation fails with:

```
RuntimeError: The 'apxs' command appears not to be installed or is not executable.
```

How can I re-build wsgi with python 3.7?

Comment: Hi Jed, I'm experiencing the exact same issue as you describe, were you able to find a solution? Thanks!

Comment: hey @Ruthus99, I should've provided my solution here as an answer, unfortunately, it's been so long I've forgotten how I resolved this. If I get a chance I'll check to see.